# How do I resolve regex parsing error while opening RStudio on Mac

Tags: macos, rstudio

I see this error when I try opening RStudio on Mac after installing it:

```
Unexpected exception: Escape sequence was neither a valid property nor a valid character class name.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'LUDE=C:\py>>>HERE>>>thon27\inc'.
```

From the log:

```
ERROR R SUICIDE: Unexpected exception: Escape sequence was neither a valid property nor a valid character class name.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'LUDE=C:\py>>>HERE>>>thon27\inc'.; LOGGED FROM: void <anonymous namespace>::rSuicide(const std::string &) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1023
```

How do I resolve the issue?

The RStudio installer version is 1.1.463. I saw the same issue with 1.1.453 as well. I am in Mac OS Sierra (version 10.12.6).

Answer (score 2):

I had some erroneous paths in `$ cat /etc/paths`. Removed them and RStudio works fine.